# Serializing object in WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I've tried everything. I've looked here and cannot find an answer. So I have an Interface

```
    public interface IUserData
{
    ExchangeVersion ExchangeVersion { get; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
    string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    string Domain { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
    Uri AutodiscoverUrl { get; set; }
    Uri ExchangeUrl { get; set; }

}
```

Concrete class

```
[DataContract]
public class UserData : IUserData
{

    public ExchangeVersion ExchangeVersion
    {
        get { return ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Domain
    {
        get;
        set;

    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Uri AutodiscoverUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Uri ExchangeUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have a service contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExchangeServiceWcf
{
    [OperationContract]
    //[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "LoginToExchange", Method = "GET")]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(UserData))]
    bool LoginToExchange(IUserData userData);

}
```

I have a Service reference and I'm calling it in my test client programm

```
ServiceReference1.ExchangeServiceWcfClient client = new ServiceReference1.ExchangeServiceWcfClient();
        bool rez;

        IUserData user = new UserData();
        user.UserName = "*****";
        user.Password = "******";
        user.Domain = "*******";
        user.EmailAddress = "*********";

        rez = client.LoginToExchange(user);
```

At line **rez** something is wrong. I always get an exception: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:userData

What's the problem?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What is the exception exactly?

Comment: Type 'WcfExchangeLibrary.Models.UserData' with data contract name 'UserData:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfExchangeLibrary.Models' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer

Comment: Have you tried [KnownType] instead of [ServiceKnownType].

Comment: Yes I have. You can only put [KnownType] to class, struct.

Comment: Everything is working now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your interface.

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(UserData))]
public interface IUserData
{
  ExchangeVersion ExchangeVersion { get; }
  string UserName { get; set; }
  string EmailAddress { get; set; }
  string Domain { get; set; }
  string Password { get; set; }
  Uri AutodiscoverUrl { get; set; }
  Uri ExchangeUrl { get; set; }
}
```